# Where can I download an old version of PostgreSQL for Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, installation, postgresql-8.4

I need version 8.4 for a legacy system, but [EnterpriseDB (the official link) only shows 9.x](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

[image]

On the [PostgreSQL FTP Mirror](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.4.22/binary/) I see the 8.4.22 binary, but only have binary for solaris:

[image]

Comment: If you are adventurous: http://www.oldapps.com/de/postgresql.php or http://www.oldversion.com/windows/postgresql/

Comment: Do you know how to compile it?

Comment: @McNets Since using visual studio only compile with F5. So long time didnt compile from a command line but can try.

Answer (score 2):

For good reason [PostgreSQL 8.4 ceased being supported at July 2014](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Moreover, PostgreSQL doesn't host compiled versions for Windows, and Enterprise DB likely doesn't want to incur the liability of hosting packages known to be insecure. Even AS-IS it becomes a question of reputation.

Upgrade your software 8.4 was released on July 2009. It's older than Windows 7.

If you must have 8.4 feel free to [download the source and compile](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/install-win32.html) or to seek out a consultant,

> PostgreSQL for Windows can be built using MinGW, a Unix-like build environment for Microsoft operating systems, or using Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler suite. The MinGW build variant uses the normal build system described in this chapter; the Visual C++ build works completely differently and is described in Chapter 16. It is a fully native build and uses no additional software like MinGW.

You can find the source for 8.4 on [git](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/REL8_4_STABLE), or in a [zip](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.4.22/)

## Archives

As others have pointed out,

> If you are adventurous: http://oldapps.com/de/postgresql.php or http://oldversion.com/windows/postgresql – a_horse_with_no_name 30 mins ago

However, whether or not you want to trust `oldapps.com` or `oldversion.com` is another question. I certainly wouldn't.

## Linux

You could always use Linux to bring yourself up to a recent version and then dump it and load it in a version supported by Windows and hosted by EnterpriseDB.

Comment: I cant upgrade the server. And need a development setup for testing.